Trouble proving the completeness of the formal system $L$ (Hilbert-style)
I would like to prove the following statement.

Suppose $\Gamma$ is a set of $L$-formulas, and $\phi$ is some $L$-formula such that for every valuation $v$ with $v(\Gamma) = T$ we have $v(\phi) = T$. Then, $\phi$ can be deduced from $\Gamma$.

I have proven the soundness, but I am having trouble going from valuations to the actual existence of the proof. As a strategy, I have also tried proving the counterpositive, however, I am having no luck (if $\phi$ can't be deduced then there exists a valuation with $\Gamma$ true and $\phi$ false).

Nevermind. This is proven with Lindenbaum's Lemma. The empty set is consistent (it is in turn the set of the axioms, which is consistent). There is a consistent and complete set $\Gamma^*$ containing the empty set. Then, apply the lemma that for this set, there exists a valuation $v(\phi) = T$ iff $\phi$ can be deduced from $\Gamma^*$.
